# Filtering query with a foreign key

Tags: django

I have the following Models:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Funnies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
```

In a case where I have a variable holding a category name (`myVar`), instead of getting all rows in Funnies that hold a reference to the category the long way:

```
category_id = Categories.objects.get(name = myVar)
funnies_list = Funnies.objects.filter(category = category_id)
```

Is there a shorter, more "django" way of getting `funnies_list` ?

Meir

Answer (score 3):

well if you have `myVar` already then

```
funnies_list = Funnies.objects.filter(category__name=myVar)
```

would work.